# How to group set of repeated specflow statements?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I would like to know , how to group set of repeated statements in Specflow scenarios. for example.

```
Given I launch xyz login page
And I enter username as ABC and password as ***** and click login
And i click on Benefits tile
And i click on Xyz section
```

Is there a way to group these statements instead of using this again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the [Background tag](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background) this will execute the methods before each scenario

```
Background:
Given I launch xyz login page
And I enter username as ABC and password as ***** and click login
And i click on Benefits tile
And i click on Xyz section
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. you can create a step which calls the other steps. The documentation for this is [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions). There is an example of this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29110773/97614)