# BDD using specflow in c#

Tags: c#

I have a feature file which have multiple scenarios where one of the scenario is to **add a payee** and the other scenario is to **delete a payee**. I want to **call** the **Add scenario in the delete one** i.e if I run the delete scenario independently then the added payee should exist and the delete scenario should run successfully.

Is there a way to call one scenario from another one?

Comment: Question seems to be similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110554/in-specflow-can-i-run-one-test-as-a-step-of-another

Comment: Thanx..I guess i got my ans...will try it :)